# UITableView is not displaying content in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

For a project, I've three UITableViews in an UITabbarController. The initial view loads the tableview correctly, but when I tap on the second tab, the table loads the right amount of cells and the right cell class, but don't show the content on it.

I logged the method `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` and every cell gets the right string values.

This is the code I use:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

    class Hapjes: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var tabel: UITableView!
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let productArray = try! Realm().objects(Product).filter("categorie = 1")

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tabel.dataSource = self
            tabel.delegate = self
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return "Hapjes"
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return productArray.count
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProductenCellHapjes", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductenCell

            var object = productArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.label.text = object.valueForKey("productNaam") as! String
            cell.plaatje.image = UIImage(named: "1449032338_news.png")

            let tmp = object.valueForKey("productNaam") as! String
            print("Hapje: \(tmp)")

            return cell
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        }

    }
```

**ProductenCell.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ProductenCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var plaatje: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

}
```

This is the screenshot of the UI how it goes now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx0Jw.png

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the cell's contentView background color? Just to confirm the cell is visible.

Comment: I think it is related to your cell configuration, check your ProductenCell class code

Comment: @zp_x I added the code of the ProductenCell class

Comment: Are you sure that your label is connected to the storyboard?

Comment: @fragilecat I've tried but seems to be ok.

Comment: @ChristianDiLorenzo Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @RickdeJong Try replacing your custom cell with a UITableViewCell and see if you can set the label's text. If you can we know the problem is with the custom cell

Comment: can you also capture a screen shot of the cell configuration in storyboard? do you setup any constraints for it? And for the image, do you put the file in image.asset? if it is, the name should be without .png postfix. Anyway, try to remove the .png and see how

Comment: @fragilecat Good point! If I'm using the basic cell style, the text will appear. It seems to be, like you said, in the ProductenCell class.

Comment: Ok, are you using a storyboard or nib to create your cell?

Comment: @fragilecat I'm using storyboards.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c20ijWYDWfI A video on creating custom UITableViewCells using storyboards :)